# Changing of integral limits.

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

I don't understand one step in an answer sheet.

Exercise: Let the function $f: [-\pi,\pi]\to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \dfrac{\sin(x)}x, & x\neq 0 \\[0.3cm] 1, &x=0 \end{cases}$$

and for $x$ outside $[-\pi,\pi]$, $f(x)$ is the periodic extension.

Show that $f(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_n e^{inx}$

where $\displaystyle c_n = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int^{(n+1)\pi}_{(n-1)\pi}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx$.

And then the answer:

\begin{align*}
  c_n &= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int^{\pi}_{-\pi}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}e^{-inx}dx\\[0.3cm]
&= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{\pi}_{-\pi}\frac{e^{ix(1-n)}-e^{-ix(1+n)}}{2ix}\, dx\\[0.3cm]
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{\pi}_{-\pi}\frac{1}{2ix}e^{-ix(n-1)}dx- \frac{1}{2\pi}
\int^{\pi}_{-\pi}\frac{1}{2ix}e^{-ix(n+1)}dx\\[0.3cm]
&= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{(n-1)\pi}_{-(n-1)\pi}\frac{1}{2iz}e^{-iz}dz -
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{(n+1)\pi}_{-(n+1)\pi}\frac{1}{2iz}e^{-iz}dz
\end{align*}

(and here finally is the step i don't understand:)

$$=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{-(n-1)\pi}_{-(n+1)\pi}\frac{1}{2iz}e^{-iz}dz -
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{(n+1)\pi}_{(n-1)\pi}\frac{1}{2iz}e^{-iz}dz
$$

Comment: $f(x)$ is a continuous, even and and $2\pi$-periodic function. You do not have to compute the coefficients of its Fourier cosine series to be able to state **there is** a Fourier cosine series.

Comment: The coefficients of the Fourier cosine series are given by sine integrals, by the way.

Comment: Is the last step because of the periodicity of $f$?

Comment: No, it is due to the fact that you are considering the difference of two integrals (of the same function) over two overlapping intervals.

Comment: If $a<b<c<d$, then $$\int_{a}^{c}f(z)\,dz - \int_{b}^{d}f(z)\,dz = \int_{a}^{b}f(z)\,dz -\int_{c}^{d}f(z)\,dz .$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have gone from integral over the Green interval - the integaral over the red interval to the the two blue intervals

[image]

$\int_{-(n-1)\pi}^{(n-1)\pi} f(z) dz - \int_{-(n+1)\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} f(z) dz\\ \int_{-(n-1)\pi}^{(n-1)\pi} f(z) dz - \int_{-(n+1)\pi}^{-(n-1)\pi} f(z) dz-\int_{-(n-1)\pi}^{(n-1)\pi} f(z) dz- \int_{(n-1)\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} f(z) dz\\
 - \int_{-(n+1)\pi}^{-(n-1)\pi} f(z) dz- \int_{(n-1)\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} f(z) dz$

Should I have a sign flip?

Comment: This was an excellent answer! I completely (I think) understood it :D